# "Conversion from string to type Double is not valid" error VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, double, type-conversion

I'm trying to display a logged in users balance from a database in VB. However once I click the Check Balance button it produces the error `Conversion from string "Your balance is " to type 'Double' is not valid`.

I've tried different ways a converting it from a string to a double, I thought maybe it was because I had m_decBalance declared as a decimal, but that didn't change anything. Can anyone help me? Here's my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
    Dim strQuery As String = ""
    Dim SQLcmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim DataReader As MySqlDataReader

    Private m_strPass As String
    Private m_decBalance As Decimal
    Private m_strName As String
    Private m_strUserPass As String
    Private m_strCardNumber As String

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        'Assign users guessed password to variable
        m_strUserPass = txtPass.Text

        'Invoke
        RetrieveAccountInformation()

        ' determine if Password is correct or not
        If m_strUserPass = m_strPass Then
            lblWelcome.Visible = True
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome" + " " + m_strName

            txtPass.Enabled = False
            btnBalance.Enabled = True
        Else
            ' indicate that incorrect password was provided
            lblWelcome.Visible = True
            lblWelcome.Text = "Sorry, Password is incorrect." _
           & "Please retry ."

            ' clear user's previous PIN entry
            m_strUserPass = ""
        End If
        txtPass.Clear() ' clear TextBox
    End Sub

    ' load application Form
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Prepare connection and query
        Try
            dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=mysql")
            strQuery = "SELECT CardNumber " &
                   "FROM Account"
            SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

            'Open the connection
            dbCon.Open()

            ' create database reader to read information from database
            DataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader

            ' fill ComboBox with account numbers
            While DataReader.Read()
                cboAccountNumbers.Items.Add(DataReader("CardNumber"))
            End While

            'Close the connection
            DataReader.Close()
            dbCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Output error message to user with explaination of error
            MsgBox("Failure to communicate" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' invoke when user provides account number
    Private Sub RetrieveAccountInformation()
        ' specify account number of record from which data will be retrieved
        dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=mysql")
        strQuery = "SELECT Name, Balance, Password " &
            "FROM Account WHERE CardNumber='" & Val(cboAccountNumbers.Text) & "' "
        SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        dbCon.Open() ' open database connection

        ' create database reader to read information from database
        DataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader
        DataReader.Read() ' open data reader connection

        ' retrieve Password number, balance amount and name information from database
        m_strPass = Convert.ToString(DataReader("Password"))
        m_decBalance = Convert.ToString(DataReader("Balance"))
        m_strName = Convert.ToString(DataReader("Name"))

        DataReader.Close() ' close data reader connection
        dbCon.Close() ' close database connection
    End Sub ' RetrieveAccountInformation

    Private Sub btnBalance_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBalance.Click
        'Retrieve their account information
        RetrieveAccountInformation()
        Try
            MsgBox("You balance is " + " " + m_decBalance)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In my database `Balance` is a integer and it's value is 200. Do I need to change it to a double in the database then or what?

Comment: @user3275784 From your error, the issue is not related to the database (please see my post below). You can leave your `Balance` column as integer (unless you need to store doubles in the database)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are joining a string with a `+`. You need to replace the `+` with `&`. I also recommend adding `.ToString` to your `m_decBalance`, as this will tell the compiler to treat `m_decBalance` as a `string`, like so:

```
MsgBox("You balance is " & " " & m_decBalance.ToString)
```

The reason you are getting the error is that the compiler tries to convert the string to a numeric value when `+` is used with a number. For example, the following will display a messagebox with the value of `10`:

```
MsgBox("5 " + " " + 5)
```

and

```
Dim Val As Integer = "20 " + 15
```

will result in `Val` being `35`

When you want to join strings, I recommend using the `&`, as this tells the compiler that you don't wish to convert the string to a number, and instead you wish to join them as strings.

I would also like to suggest using `Option Strict On`, as this will help prevent errors like this from happening, as it prevent you from recompiling if you have any `implicit conversions` (where the compiler has to guess which type you want to convert to)

Answer (score 0):

use `&` for string concatenation. You are using `+`

```
MsgBox("You balance is " & " " & m_decBalance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the '&' symbol for connecting strings to other

```
MsgBox("You balance is " & " " & m_decBalance)
```